# How to get Height of ImageView when it is set to wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

So deal is i am setting image dynamically to imageview and i have set imageview height as wrapcontent, so how can i get height of imageview layout after setting image from server i tried this code but its giving height of drawable,

```
imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
```

and i also tried with this but was getting height as zero.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
```

actually there is 2nd layout which depends on the height of imageview, i mean i want to overlay 2nd layout on imageview by setting 75% of imageview height to 2nd layout as marginTop,
[image: Something like this image]
please help Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem.

Where you calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on ImageView? If you calling from `onCreate()` in activity, it won't work. You need to wait for activity window to attached and then call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on ImageView. You can try calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` from `onWindowFocusChanged()` method of your activity.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    int width=imageView.getWidth();
    int height=imageView.getHeight();
}
```

or use `ViewTreeObserver` in `onWindowsFocusChanged` it will work

```
int finalHeight, finalWidth;

final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scaled_image);
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.size_label);
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        finalHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
        finalWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
        tv.setText("Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Try this one in your activitie's `onCreate()` and do let me know

```
imageView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int width = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
                int height = iv.getMeasuredHeight();

            }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Check the updated answer, your problem was you were using it in onCreate() method , you have to wait for the window to attach the view.

Comment: Lets try it every where, i.e onResume() onStart() , and are you using?? emulator?

Comment: @AbdulKawee, I also wonder what is a device. In emulator and any other devices your code will work.

Comment: m trying in  emulator

Comment: @CoolMind , what i think its better to test the code in emulator and devices also, as emulator do have some limitations

Comment: @AKSHAYMANAGOOLI try it in some devices and then check the results

Comment: Yeah sure do try it in different devies